# Basic LED voltage

Tags: voltage, led

Sorry this is a very basic question from a complete novice.

I need to replace a 3 mm through hole LED, I have tested the voltage coming from the board and it's 4.5 V. I can't find a 3 mm LED with 4.5 V; the highest I can find is 3.6 V. Will the 3.6 work or will it blow the LED?

Comment: Did you test this voltage across the LED in-circuit or with the LED removed?  Why are you replacing the LED in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for the link, I am still not sure! I have never worked with boards and LED's before.

Comment: I tested the voltage on the board without the LED connected as the LED is dead, on the board its just a connecter with 2 wires connecting it to the LED

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace it with a similar or larger one should work, preferably of the same color or shorter wavelength.  The voltage across the LED will drop to whatever the LED requires because there is a series resistor internally (assuming it was properly wired to begin with, of course).

Comment: Looks like it does have a resistor, its one of these https://uk.farnell.com/rcd-resistors-coils-delaylines/blu1206-1000-tt10w/res-thin-film-100r-0-01-0-25w/dp/1614533?pf_custSiteRedirect=true

Comment: Then it should work. The longer lead on the new LED is the + lead generally.

Comment: I have just removed one of the working LED's and tested it, when its illuminated its 3v so I am guessing I just need a 3v LED

Comment: The voltage is not well defined (it varies with current for one thing), any 3mm LED that has a catalog Vf between 2.4 and 3.4 ish should work well. In practice that means any visible 3mm LED that is not red.

Comment: Great thank you

Answer (score 3):

LEDs are driven by a current limited source - not a constant voltage. In most cases for an indicator LED a simple resistor does the job. Your board probably has this built in and if you trace back from the LED solder pads you may be able to identify it.

[image]

*Figure 1. Series connection of a resistor and LED. The voltmeters show the voltage drop across each element of the circuit. Image source: [LEDnique](http://lednique.com/electrical-theory-basics/ohms-law-and-resistor-calculation/).*

If you remove the LED in the circuit above the voltmeter would read 5 V, that of the supply.

If you can find the on-board resistor then you can connect the new LED with a high degree of confidence.